# Cross-Region DynamoDB Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I haven't been able to find a clear answer on this from the documentation.

Is is discouraged to access DynamoDB from outside the region it is hosted in? For example, I want to do a lot of writes to a DynamoDB table in `us-west-2`, from a cluster in `us-east-1` (or even `ap-southeast-1`). My writes are batched and non-real-time, so I don't care so much about a *small* increase in latency.

Note that I am **not** asking about cross-region replication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB is a hosted solution but that doesn't mean you need to be inside AWS to use it.

There are cases, especially for [storing user information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) for clients making queries against DynamoDB - outside of "AWS region".

So to answer your question - best performance will be achieved when you mitigate the geo barrier, but you can work with any endpoint you'd like from anywhere in the world.